# Create table with rows from object

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am facing with a problem creating a table with an array of nested objects.

I have an array with this schema:

```
array = [
    {
        id: 'Column1',
        rows: {
            row1: 'A',
            row2: 'B',
            row3: 'C',
            row4: 'D'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'Column2',
        rows: {
            row1: 'E',
            row2: 'F',
            row3: 'G',
            row4: 'H'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'Column3',
        rows: {
            row1: 'I',
            row2: 'J',
            row3: 'K',
            row4: 'L'
        }
    }
];
```

And I am trying to create a table that looks like this: 
[image]

I was able to create the columns heads but I dont know how to do the body of it.

Any clue about how to work with it?

```
<table class="table table-users table-fixed table-striped">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-2">
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-2" *ngFor="let col of array">{{col.id}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-data">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you need to use `*ngFor` on the table rows for each element of the array - another neat solution I personally prefer is ngx-datatable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would make your template as simple as possible and convert the data just after it's retrieved. [Something like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-convert):

```
public table = this.convertToTable(this.array);

private convertToTable(array: { id: string, rows: any }[]) {
    // get the property name and value of the columns rows.
    // sort the array by length so the first and largest array can be used to get the properties names.
    const columnRows = array.map(a => ((Object as any).entries(a.rows)).
        map(([rowHeader, rowValue]) => ({ rowHeader, rowValue })))
        .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
    // get the headers
    const headers = array.map(a => a.id);
    // create rows by looping through the largest array with rowValues
    const rows = columnRows.length > 0 ?
        columnRows[0].map((v, rowIndex) => {
            const rowValues = headers.map((_, columnIndex) => {
                const row = columnRows.length > columnIndex ? columnRows[columnIndex] : [];
                const rowValue = row.length > rowIndex ? row[rowIndex].rowValue : null;
                return rowValue;
            });
            return {
                rowHeader: v.rowHeader,
                rowValues
            };
        }) : [];
    return { headers, rows };
}
```

And the Html:

```
<table border='1' class="table table-users table-fixed table-striped">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-2">
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-2" *ngFor="let header of table.headers">
          {{header}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of table.rows">
      <td>{{row.rowHeader }}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let value of row.rowValues">
        {{value}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use nested `*ngFor` like this -

```
<table border='1' class="table table-users table-fixed table-striped">
    <caption></caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-2">
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="col-xs-2" *ngFor="let col of array">{{col.id}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let col of array">
      <th *ngFor="let item of col.rows | keyvalue; let i = index">
        <span *ngIf='!i'>{{item.key}} </span>
        <span *ngIf='i'>{{item.value}}</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-ngforloop?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: ..was just about to write the same ;) +1

Comment: kudos buddy! thinking is mutual :P @iLuvLogix

Comment: Hmm I see but it only print 3 rows intead all of them :S

Comment: @Arm144 you have added only 3 rows in your JSON format in question, check that, also If data is in same format, will work for all for sure.

Comment: the datastructure is quite ackward btw.. @PardeepJain it's actually not a valid json but a normal js-object of type array ;)

Comment: @PardeepJain no, I added 3 columns but 4 rows-> rows: {
            row1: 'E',
            row2: 'F',
            row3: 'G',
            row4: 'H'
        }

Comment: @iLuvLogix nope

Comment: @Arm144 Bro Logic is self explanatory, No one here code for you as per your requirement. Tweak some changes and you will get the result. I hope you understand.

Comment: @PardeepJain Im not asking to do it for me, I am just aking to give me some tips, you can see it in the part where I say "any clue".The thing is that the first for loop only iterates over 3 elements and if you are assigning it to the <tr> it will only represent 3 rows when I want 4. thats my real problem, and thats why I am asking here. I expent already 4 hours trying it (and already tried before the example that you gave me and edit it, that I really apreciate).
If thats all that all what we can do, I'll try to modify the data model to archieve it what I want. Thank you Bro for your time.

Comment: I think you are confused with row and column count, you want to print 4 column not rows, right? So you can enhance the code in some manner but this logic will iterate over the array of each elements and print it in the form of rows. Thank you.

Comment: @PardeepJain check my own answer, there you have what I wanted and see how I resolved it if you are in the same case on the future

Comment: @Arm144 If you look more closely your and mine answers are almost same, One thing which is not so recommended in your code is, Always avoid to use method binding in the template which you did, basically it makes computation heavy. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I found a solution spliting the original array in 2, the original used for the columns and the second to show the rows.

After that created a method to only obtain the values for each row.

Here is the solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bn2mgw

Comment: Self answer is always good, @Arm144 If you look more closely your and mine answers are almost same, One thing which is not so recommended in your code is, Always avoid to use method binding in the template which you did, basically it makes computation heavy.